# Having error on cv::threshold while using it in a class but on a normal “main entry point” works fine

Tags: c++, opencv

Below is my class Function that use cv::threshold. the functionality of it is to check if there any diffreneces of two images 1) it loads the images into cv::Mat 2)find diffrenence 3)apply threshold 4)apply dilate 5) find contours 6) get all contours and store them in a map.
But as soon as it reach to the function “cv::threshold” the cassert throws an error says buffer_size % 2 == 0

```
BOOL AI::detectDifferences(std::string firstFileName, std::string secondFileName)
            {
                //MatrixImage is just typedef of cv::Mat
                MatrixImage img0 = cv::imread("Assets/Image/popcorn0.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
                MatrixImage img1 = cv::imread("Assets/Image/popcorn1.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

                MatrixImage destination;
                cv::absdiff(img0, img1, destination);

                cv::Mat threshold;
                //cv::threshold(destination, threshold, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
                cv::threshold(destination, threshold, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
                
                MatrixImage dilate;
                MatrixImage kernel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(2, 2), cv::Point(-1, -1));
                cv::dilate(threshold, dilate, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), -1);

                std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
                std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

                cv::findContours(dilate, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                this->mapVecRect.insert(std::pair<std::string, OpenCVVectorRect*>(secondFileName, new OpenCVVectorRect()));
                for (auto& i : contours)
                {
                    if (cv::contourArea(i) > 100)
                    {
                        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(i);
                        mapVecRect[secondFileName]->push_back(rect);
                    }
                }
                return TRUE;
            }
```

Comment: Sounds like threshold() is not happy with it's source image. Have you checked that img0, img1, destination all have data in them ? Are your paths correct ? Also, i don't know how Otsu handles all black images, but thats probably not whats happening here.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. I can't find `buffer_size % 2` assertion in OpenCV source code. The error could be related to JPEG image reading or to `this->mapVecRect.insert`. Make sure you are debugging the code with optimizations turned off (`/Od` or `-O0`). It is very unlikely that the error is coming from `cv::threshold`. Since it's related to "using it in a class", the issue is probably related to `this->mapVecRect.insert`.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is that i am using UTF-16 encoding while the library uses UTF-8

Comment: UTF-8 is superior anyway.